# How can we simulate the app being killed in background using Appium?

Tags: android, appium

Android may kill an application to reclaim memory any time that it is paused.  The system will then provided saved state to the application if and when it is resumed. We would like Appium to be able test this case.  In manual testing we put the app in the background, kill the process using ADB, and then resume the app.  How can we kill the process or otherwise simulate the situation where the application has been forced out by the OS and resumed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

The `driver.closeApp()` function should be what you're looking for. It does "kill the app", "remove from cache", etc in iOS, but you'll need to give it a test in Android.